# Prove $\left \langle (1 \;3), (1\; 2\;3\; 4) \right \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is to prove $\left \langle (1 \;3), (1\; 2\;3\; 4)  \right \rangle$  is a proper subgroup of $S_4$. What is the easiest way of proving? Thanks.

Comment: It's the group generated by those two elements, @Gold

Comment: Oh..yum confused with the notation

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by computing the powers of your elements in the generating set and the product of powers, to determine the elements in the set.

We know that the set of elements generated by $\alpha = (1, 3)$ and $\beta = (1, 2, 3, 4)$, is closed under powers and composition of $\alpha, \beta$ and is in $S_4$.  You are guaranteed closure because the elements of $S_4$ are closed under permutation composition in $S_4$.

You'll have that the identity permutation of $S_4$ is in $H$ (note that $id = \alpha^2 = \beta^4$) and

You'll have that for each element, its inverse is in $H$.

When you've simply exhausted the composition of all products of powers of elements in $H$, (which won't take terribly long to do) you will find that $H$ is indeed a subgroup of $S_4$, and the order of $H$ is less than, and divides, the order of $S_4$, and hence a *proper* subgroup of $S_4$.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, there's an easier way to see that the subgroup is not all of $S_4$. Since this is almost surely a homework problem, I'll just give a hint:

Say a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is "fair" if $\pi(1)$ and $\pi(3)$ have the same parity (both odd or both even) and (equivalently) $\pi(2)$ and $\pi(4)$ have the same parity.

- Is $\alpha$ a fair permutation?
- Is $\beta$ a fair permutation?
- Is the composition of two fair permutations again fair?
- Is every permutation in $S_4$ fair?

Answer (score 2):

If you take the numbers to correspond to $4$ seats around a table, then both of your operations (exchange the persons on one particular pair of opposite places respectively move everyone around one place) preserve relation of being opposite (both pairs of people facing one another still do so after each of the operations). The whole subgroup $H$ that the two permutations generate will also preserve that relation, but since not all possible permutations do so, $H\neq S_4$. In fact since one can be opposite to three different persons, one sees that $[S_4:H]$ must be a multiple of$~3$ (in fact it is$~3$).

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

We already know the structure of $S_4$. It consists of such elements which are all the permutations of the $4$ alphabet (or numbers $\{1,2,3,4\}$). This shows that two permutations $a=(1,3)$ and $b=(1,2,3,4)$ are in this group undoubtedly. This also grantees that both of them can generate a subgroup of $S_4$. Let $H=\left \langle a,b  \right \rangle$. But what is this subgroup? We can easily check that $a^2=b^4=1$. But is there any other relationship between $a$ and $b$? [Triangle Groups](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_group) tells us to think about the possible value of $n$ in which $(ab)^n=\text{id}$. Since manipulating with these two permutation is not hard so we can examine some powers to find the proper $n$. $$(ab)^2=\text{id}$$ Therefore, we can show the subgroup $H$ as follows:

$$H= \langle a,b \mid a^2=b^4=(ab)^2=1\rangle=\{1,a,b,b^2,b^3,ab,ab^2,ab^3\}$$ $H$ is well known dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8\neq 4!$.